# Создание приложения по работе с НПА

Tags: c#

Подскажите как это работает: 
к примеру, у меня есть небольшая база нормативно-правовых актов, которая нуждается в обновлении, стабильно, раз в пол года. И вот я хочу написать десктопное приложение, которое будет обновлять эту самую базу. База - каталог, в котором есть несколько папок, в которых хранятся необходимые документы в формате .docx. Как я думал, может есть сайт, на котором хранятся в актуальном состоянии документы, и у этого сайта есть API для взаимодействия с этой базой. Но, либо я не нашел такой сайт, либо я не в ту сторону думал. Вопрос в том, какие есть варианты для того, чтобы получать обновления для локальной базы НПА?

Comment: https://regulation.gov.ru/opendata/7710349494-npalist/ ???

Comment: Забыл уточнить,что для региона Беларуси. Поэтому и не могу найти подходящий сайт.